# How to highlight table rows by hover over another div?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

i have two tables

```
<table id='standings'>
<tr id='tableTeam1'>
<td>Team1</td>
</tr>
<tr id='tableTeam2'>
<td>Team2</td>
</tr>
<tr id='tableTeam3'>
<td>Team3</td>
</tr>
</table>




<table id='matches'>
<tr id='match1'>
<td id='matchTeam1>Team1</TD>
<td class='score'> 22-31</td>
<td id='matchTeam3>Team3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My goal is to hover over the row with id 'match1' from the second table and have the rows with id 'tableTeam1' and 'tableTeam3' highlighted

1.)
how is this possible by js/css?

2.) How can it be done by using a php database request when
"Select tableTeam1,tableTeam2 from matches where id='match1'"

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this:

```js
$('#match1')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#tableTeam1').addClass('highlighted');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#tableTeam1').removeClass('highlighted');
    })
```

You also need to add some CSS there, like this one:

```
.highlighted { background-color: red;}
```

2. I don't know your data structure but it should be something like that, I think:

```php
...
<tr id="<?php echo $data['column_name']; ?>" <?php echo ($data['column_name'] === 'match1')? 'class="highlighted"' : ''; ?>>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your team numbers in a data attribute in rows of the matches then it is fairly simple to  parse them to match the elements in the other table and toggle a class on them

```js
$('#matches .match-row').hover(function() {
  const teams = $(this).data('teams');
  teams.forEach(num => $('#tableTeam' + num).toggleClass('active'))
})
```

```css
tr.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='standings' border=1>
  <tr id='tableTeam1'>
    <td>Team1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='tableTeam2'>
    <td>Team2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id='tableTeam3'>
    <td>Team3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id='matches' border=1>
  <tr class="match-row" data-teams="[1,3]">
    <td>Team1</td>
    <td class='score'> 22-31</td>
    <td>Team3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="match-row" data-teams="[2,3]">
    <td>Team2</td>
    <td class='score'> 55-1 Blowout!</td>
    <td>Team3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```